# Error While Booting Blender on Computer without GPU

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I'm trying to use an old server to do Cycles rendering, The only issue is when I try to boot blender, I get the following errors.

```
AL lib: (EE) ALmmdevPlayback_open: Device init failed: 0x80070490
Warning! Using result of ChoosePixelFormat
Warning! Using result of ChoosePixelFormat
Warning! Legacy WGL is unable to select between OpenGL versions.
```

Is there a way I can get blender to open so I can render the project?

I will be making the blender file on a different computer with a GPU, unfortunately I can't render on that computer as I need to use it for school.

Server Specs:

No Graphics Card

Intel Xeon E5520 @ 2.27GHz, 2261 Mhz, 4 cores,

Windows 10

Comment: Are you booting from GUI or Command Line?

Comment: @ScottMilner I’ve tried both

Comment: The first line is from the openal sound library the other is opengl. Do you have openal and opengl installed? Have you tried from the cli using `-b` to run it without a gui?